# Web Server with phpMyAdmin

Tags: linux, local-area-network, rhel5

We have web development company, We using RHEL 5  as local (proxy) server with few windows XP client machines.

Now i want to make my Server machine as Web Server ( LAN only ), with mysql and phpMyAdmin.

I installed httpd,php,mysql by yum. `How to install phpMyAdmin ?` And Where i want to installl ?

Now i want to make my client machines can create php files in web folder, Also use mysql and phpMyAdmin.

How can i do it ? Give me clear steps to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is in Debian repository. Isn't it also in RHEL? I prefer installation from repository, not from tar.gz, because otherwise you have to manually install it again and again with new release.

Answer (score 0):

Download phpMyAdmin from http://www.phpmyadmin.net, create a virtual host for phpMyAdmin on your server or simply create a phpMyAdmin folder in your DocumentRoot directory.  Extract the files into the new directory phpMyAdmin directory and modify the config.php file as needed.